# SSH as user allowing temporary root access in Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, root

I want to SSH a CentOS server as user X, say (not root). I then want to transfer files to the server. That is easy enough. But then I want to move the files to a "pool" where all users can access them, i.e. outside user X's directory.

Can I do this? I don't want to login as root for various reasons, including security issues. I basically want my script, which moves the file from user X's directory to an outside directory, to have root privelages temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has essentially nothing to do with SSH. You are just asking "can set up a group of files on a Unix system so that all users can access them", and the answer is of course.

You don't explain much about what you're trying to do, but the chmod, mv and mkdir man pages should help you figure out what you need here.

Comment: Fair point. It's just the whole thing is through SSH as everyone who uses the pool will be on remote devices, so my brain is on a SSH one-track mind. The purpose is pretty straightforward. I want users to upload files to the server (users are not in the same group) and put the files in one central location.

Comment: Do you need the files to be readable by all or also writable by all? Anyway, it seems like all you really need is to set up a common directory for the users to put their files into and have the permissions on that directory and the files set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no problem with making *pool* directory writable by ssh user you can just

```
scp file user@host:/srv/pool
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not fully understanding the question, but it seems the easiest way to accomplish what you want is not by running the script with root privileges but by relaxing the directory permissions of the target, "outside," directory.

If you set the [sticky bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) then anyone can you want can place files in that directory, including the script, but only the original owner can delete and/or rename the files inside.

However, if this doesn't do it for you, getting Bash to run as root is  [pretty straight forward.](http://blog.mecworks.com/articles/2006/02/23/bash-scripting-tip-running-a-script-as-root/) However, keep in mind the rule of thumb that the more holes you put into your system, well, the more holes it will have.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use `rsync` over SSH, the way most people do. There's two possibilities:

- Reverse the data transfer: start the rsync session on the machine owning the pool directory, and **pull** the files. That way you can store with --numeric-ids and whatever fancy you need (e.g. device files, hard links...) because the external machine only **provides** the data, it does not actually upload it.
- Use my technique from [here](http://janzzstimmpfle.de/~jens/softcrap/backup-technique/) . It's actually pretty similar to the above method, though most disadvantages are avoided.

Answer (score 0):

$sudo chmod 777 /path/to/dir

$sudo chmod +t /path/to/dir

use the stick bit will sovle your problem.